# Upgrading Laravel 5.1 to 5.2: Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::createDriver()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

Upgrading Laravel from 5.1 to 5.2 gives me an error after upgrading and running the project.

I have followed Laravel's documentation of upgrading from 5.1 to 5.2 (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0).

Also, I updated my config/app.php to the one found here: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/develop/config/auth.php

After the upgrade, running my Laravel project gives me an error:

```
ErrorException in AuthManager.php line 16:
Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::createDriver()
```

Has anyone upgraded successfully and resolved this error?

Comment: I had similiar issue. It's because you are using old AuthServiceProvider in app/config/app.php

just remove or comment out the line Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider you'll be fine.

Comment: @Rodrane Hmm...doing so now gives me `Class auth.driver does not exist`

Comment: having the same issue did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @mbouzahir I was able to upgrade by going a very manual route. I downloaded 5.2 and overwrote my project. I used git to keep all the files I created (views, Controllers, Requests, Models, etc.) and also to track the differences. Some you'll want to change and some you'll want to keep as you have had previously. I had to carefully look at each file and adjust my code base accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by deleting the cache files out of bootstrap/cache